# Не могу подключиться к localdb после публикации

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Всем привет. После публикации проекта на сервер в логе появилась ошибка подключения к localdb. На обычном ПК в Visual Studio у меня всё отлично работает. В чём может быть причина?

Ошибка:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server '(localdb)\DeptLocalDB'.
```

Полный файл лога: [log](https://pastebin.com/zbVaxfWP)

Строка подключения: `Data Source=(localdb)\\DeptLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False`

Состояние базы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хостится на сервере в IIS? Учетка пула приложений имеет доступ к БД?

Comment: localdb на сервере установлен?

Comment: Установлен на IIS. Насчёт localdb не понял вопрос, я выше указал скриншот, что база активна. Возможно что-то не так понял.

Comment: `Учетка пула приложений имеет доступ к БД?`

Comment: Я не понял этот вопрос. Как это узнать или изменить?

Comment: у вас в строке подключения `Integrated Security=True;` то есть под каким юзером запущен процесс - под ним прога в БД и будет заходить.  У IIS есть пул приложений, элемент пула, кроме прочего, устанавливает по каким юзером будет запустаться сайт который к этому элементу пула относится. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: IIS по умолчанию будет сайты запускать под каким то своим аккаунтом (точно не помню по каким), вам надо зайти в пул приложений IIS и там поглядеть/настроить юзера, под каоторым сайт будет запущен

Comment: Чтобы убедиться, что проблема в IIS, если у вас dotnet core, то вы можете запустить сайт сначала в консоли, если в консоли он будет работать, а в IIS нет - то прблема в IIS

Comment: Насколько я понял, IIS запущен от имени администратора. https://i.imgur.com/36CpQwR.png

Comment: Сайт то работает, загружается Index, но при первом получении данных из db, я получаю ошибку.

Comment: нет, это вы зашли за администратора, а ваш сайт от учетки по умолчанию запущен https://i.stack.imgur.com/7etOo.png

Comment: Я добавил юзера - https://i.imgur.com/jFa6f0l.png Поместил его в админы - https://i.imgur.com/epDJxPx.png Изменил пользователя у пула - https://i.imgur.com/kWgz48m.png Но ошибка осталась та же - https://pastebin.com/q1ApeyTP

Comment: Хотя нет, теперь пишет что экземпляра дб не существует.

Comment: localdb вообще для целей разработки используется, если вы разворачиваете приложение на боевом сервере и пускаете в продакшн, то лучшем выходом будет использование полноценного подключения к SQL SERVER.

Comment: Я его установил, но он агрессивный какой-то, ничего с ним не работало, с localdb  я начал другие ошибки получать постепенно, решил сначала с ним разобраться. Сейчас попробую приконектится к обычной базе.

Comment: Ребяяятаааа, 2 дня страдал, получилось с обычной базой SQL Express. Спасибо большое